# Conclusions from Fourier series equality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-series

Assume a periodic, continuous function $f$ admits two Fourier series expansions
$$f(x)= \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx)$$
and
$$f(x)= \frac{c_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n\cos(nx) + d_n\sin(nx)$$
with uniform convergence. But then one can write 
$$0=\frac{a_0-c_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n-c_n)\cos(nx) + (b_n-d_n)\sin(nx)$$
still with uniform convergence. What is the easiest way from here to deduce that $a_n-c_n=0$ for all $n$?

Comment: Square the right-hand side and integrate on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$. Many terms will vanish by orthogonality leaving you with a sum of squares. A sum of squares vanishes if and only if each summand vanishes, and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose 
$$
f(x)= \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx)
$$
*uniformly* on $[0,2\pi]$. Then, 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos x\,dx
=\int_{0}^{2\pi} 
\left(\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx)\right)\cos x\,dx.
$$
But "uniform" convergence allows you the switch the integral and summation signs, which implies that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos x\,dx=a_1\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^2x\,dx=a_1\pi.
$$
With the exactly same argument, 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos x\,dx=c_1\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^2x\,dx=c_1\pi.
$$
This tells you that $a_1=c_1$.

Similarly, you can show that $a_n=c_n$, by multiplying $f$ with $\cos(nx)$, and $b_n=d_n$, by multiplying $f$ with $\sin(nx)$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $g$ the second expression, then you can compute $\langle f - g, h\rangle$, where $h(x) = \cos(nx)$ or $h(x) = \sin(nx)$, then since $f=g$ the inner product is zero but by direct computation it will be $a_n - c_n$ or $b_n - d_n$.